# Facebook FQL query weird - does not give all results

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have an FQL query to get all of pages that all of my friends like.

`select page_id,uid from page_fan where uid in(select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())`

I realized this was not returning all the results. However it was not due to capping as number of results is ~4000, less than the cap of 5000.

Proof of this is

```
results.collect{|result| result["uid"]}.uniq.count 
=> 33
```

*Translation for non-rubyists: Count of all unique friend UIDs is `33`

However, I have >100 friends who ALL like at least one page

Any idea on why my FQL query is not giving all the results?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with the Facebook API since the beginning.  Facebook trades off accuracy for speed by giving "eh, that's close enough" answers to API calls.  You can try using the Graph API to get more results (it *will* give a different number of results), but you'll likely have to just settle with "close enough".

Comment: that would be fine if it were giving 95% of the results, but < 30% not acceptable.

Comment: :)  I didn't say it was right, good, or acceptable...  It's just how it is.  The percentage of results returned depend entirely on the answer set.  If a person has 10 friends, I'm sure you'll get the complete list every time.

Comment: just happened this to me today, it pretty much sucks, I would recommend anyone to stay away from FQL

Answer (score 1):

By what i can see this is pretty much related to ACCESS_TOKEN.

I have this problem ( AND IT SUCKS! ) but when trying the same query on the "explorer tool": https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer it seems to work perfectly.

I guess cause somehow its guarantees the ACCESS_TOKEN for you. I have queries where i explicit ask for 20 images and come about 6. Its so LAME.